# Deleting rows from id table based off of data from three corresponding tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'node' wich has a column 'nid'. This id corresponds to the column 'entity_id' in three other tables. The three tables we'll call 'pop', 'city', 'state'. The 'city' and 'state' tables have city_value and state_value columns respectively.

Not all 'city' and 'state' table rows have a corresponding 'entity_id' in the 'pop' table.

From this I can get two sets of data. Nodes that have and entity_id in the pop table (setA) and those that don't (setB).

To get setA I do this:

```
SELECT nid FROM node
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pop
  ON node.nid = pop.entity_id
  WHERE pop.entity_id IS NOT null
```

I can't figure out how to delete rows in 'node' from setB that have the same city and state as setA.

EDIT: I had m.entity_id in my setA code but it should have been pop.entity_id in the WHERE line.

EDIT: I think I have it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT setB.nid FROM 

(
    SELECT DISTINCT AA.nid, AA.title, BB.field_dialup_number_city_value, CC.field_dialup_number_state_value FROM 
    (   
        SELECT node.nid, node.title FROM node LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_dialup_number_popcode pop  
        ON node.nid = pop.entity_id WHERE pop.entity_id IS NOT null  
    ) AA
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_dialup_number_city BB ON AA.nid = BB.entity_id 
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_dialup_number_state CC ON AA.nid = CC.entity_id
) setB


INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.nid, A.title, B.field_dialup_number_city_value, C.field_dialup_number_state_value FROM 
    (   
        SELECT node.nid, node.title FROM node LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_dialup_number_popcode pop  
        ON node.nid = pop.entity_id WHERE pop.entity_id IS null  
    ) A
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_dialup_number_city B ON A.nid = B.entity_id 
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_dialup_number_state C ON A.nid = C.entity_id
) setA


ON setA.field_dialup_number_state_value = setB.field_dialup_number_state_value

WHERE setA.field_dialup_number_city_value = setB.field_dialup_number_city_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said setA is

```
SELECT nid FROM node  
LEFT OUTER JOIN pop  
ON node.nid = pop.entity_id  
WHERE m.entity_id IS NOT null
```

setB would be just a JOIN WHERE NULL

```
SELECT nid FROM node  
LEFT OUTER JOIN pop  
ON node.nid = pop.entity_id  
WHERE m.entity_id IS null
```

If you want setA to connect back to city and state, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.nid FROM
(
    SELECT nid FROM node LEFT OUTER JOIN pop  
    ON node.nid = pop.entity_id WHERE m.entity_id IS NOT null  
) A
INNER JOIN  city B ON A.nid = B.entity_id 
INNER JOIN state C ON A.nid = C.entity_id 
;
```

If you want setB to connect back to city and state, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.nid FROM
(
    SELECT nid FROM node LEFT OUTER JOIN pop  
    ON node.nid = pop.entity_id WHERE m.entity_id IS null  
) A
INNER JOIN  city B ON A.nid = B.entity_id 
INNER JOIN state C ON A.nid = C.entity_id 
;
```

Comment: I only want to delete rows from 'node' when the state and city match for both setA and setB as I explained above. Your first code block would delete setB entirely.

Comment: This is where I come into trouble. I would then need to get the city and state from **setB** and if there was the same city and state combination in **setA** I would delete the `node.nid` that corresponds to the **setB** `entity_id`

Comment: Shouldn't node.nid exist in city, state, and pop as entity_id?

Comment: Yes, node.nid exists in those tables as entity_id.

Comment: I think I figured it out from what you showed me. Edit is above. Thank you.